# how to return all not FirstOrDefault in MVC controller LINQ

Tags: linq, model-view-controller

How to return all rows matches the id no not only FirstOrDefault ?

This is the code i used :

```
return context.LAB_RESULTS_CLINIC_VIEW.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Patient_No ==id);
```

and return only one row , i need to return all rows for passed id no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Where` is a base LINQ operator. Better to learn all of them.

```
return context.LAB_RESULTS_CLINIC_VIEW.Where(e => e.Patient_No == id).ToList();
```